# Running Parse code after another has finished execution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, concurrency

I'm trying to query a class of objects with specific ID's to delete. When I run it however, I get an error for **"This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done"**. I assume this is because I'm trying to delete an object while I'm still accessing it.

I've provided the deletion code in the closure because I'm assuming the closure statements only execute after the function call finishes, yet it's still giving me the error. I've also tried using DispatchGroups because it does seem like a concurrency issue, but I'm not too familiar with their usage yet. Here's my code:

```
let idList = [...] // Some list of ID's I would like to remove

let query = PFQuery(className: "Pictures")

for id in idList {
    query.getObjectInBackground(withId: id) { (object: PFObject?, error: 
Error?) in
    if error == nil {
        img?.deleteInBackground() { (success, error: Error?) ...
    } 
}
```

I'm expecting each object associated with an ID in my original IdList to be deleted from the Parse backend. However, it seems that getObjectInbackground() and deleteInBackground() are clashing. If anyone could provide some advice, that would be wonderful!

Comment: Not tried it but can you try to put `let query = PFQuery(className: "Pictures")` inside the for loop and see if error still exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var idList = [...]

func delete(_ id:Int) {
     query.getObjectInBackground(withId: id) { (object: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
           if error == nil {
              img?.deleteInBackground() { (success, error: Error?) ...
           }

          idList  = Array(idList.dropFirst())
          if !idList.isEmpty {
            delete(idList.first!)
          }
    } 
}
```

Initially call it like

```
delete(idList.first!)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me! I used your recursive approach along with DispatchGroups to handle batch deletes and was able to get a working solution.

Comment: @TamNguyen - if the answer worked - please mark the answer as correct.  Click the up arrow.